# I want to remove the directory name from the url for default language in wpml plugin wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, wpml

I am using wpml plugin for language translation. Problem I am facing is i don't want directory name in the url for the default language. Now url is like 
`http://example.com/en/~filename` For default language but I want `http://example.com/~filename`. Can you provide me solution for this.

Comment: As I know, the WPML doesn't have subdirectory as default language. Have you checked your settings: Default language? Are you sure is not a different language by default?

Comment: @LeoCaseiro  In WPML -> Languages-> Language URL format. We have option for displaying url format  one option is ** Different languages in directories**. i  have selected that one. Because i want url with directory name for second language and for default language without directory name.

Answer (score 0):

If setting of plugin does not help, you can use such rule in htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/*$ /en/$1
```

Comment: can you please tell me where to put this in htaccess.
`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/*$ /de/$1
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`

Comment: got internal server error when put code after rewrite base

Comment: To avoid error, add `RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} /index.php` before. Else infinite loop occures. But I don't understand, how your language switch is working now and will work.

Comment: wpml creating virtual directories.eg like if i have two language en and de then its making url with directory name like `http://www.example.com/en/` and `http://www..example.com/de/` as `de` language is default for that i want http://www.example.com.

Comment: What is happening after adding  RewriteCond ?

Comment: its not removing anything from the url.its still the same but internal error gone

Comment: @Learner i was in off-line. there full text of htacces. it works, i think - https://eval.in/393533

Comment: I just want to remove the directory name using htaccess. nothing else `http://www.example.com/en/~filename ` to `http://www.example.com/~filename`.So i need rule for this.Earlier rules doesn't work

Comment: if you stay in htaccess only `RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [L]`